# Seeking explanation regarding onclick listeners in nested jsx components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick, react-component

Good morning,

I am writing a React application and ran into an interesting situation that I was hoping somebody with knowledge of how `Javascript`, `React` (and maybe HTML as well) work could explain for me.

Consider the following two pieces of code as a part of the return statement in a `React` functional component:

consider:

```
<ul>
    {props.theProp.map((foo) => {
        <li>
            <Foo /* props */ onClick={() => bar.fooHarder()} />
        </li>
        })}
</ul>
```

against:

```
<ul>
    {props.theProp.map((foo) => {
        <li onClick={() => bar.fooHarder()} >
            <Foo /* props */ />
        </li>
        })}
</ul>
```

Please explain to me why the click listener in the first piece of code did nothing whilst the second worked as expected.

What is it about `JavaScript` (`React`? HTML?) that causes this?  Why does it not also apply to `CSS` pseudo classes (in this case I have the cursor for  set to pointer which works just fine)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first piece of code, since `li` is an HTML element, the event listener is *automatically* bound to the `li` element.

In the second piece of code, `Foo` is a **React Component**, meaning that the `onClick` is passed as a `prop` to the `Foo` component and not yet bound.

If you want the event to be bound to the `Foo` component, you have to use its `onClick` prop.

Something like:

```
import React from 'react';

function Foo ({ onClick }) {
  return <button onClick={onClick}>Click me!</button>;
}

export default Foo;
```